# Using COM libraries in Win10 Core IoT?

Tags: com, windows-10-iot-core

I want to create an IoT application in VisualStudio 2015 community and want to add a reference to Windows Portable Device, which is a COM library. But the whole COM tab is missing from the references window. Is there a way to include COM libraries in Windows 10 Core IoT, or is that impossible? If the second, does that mean I would have to write drivers for any USB devices myself?

Comment: No, you are definitely barking up the wrong tree.  Support for Automation and legacy COM type libraries is discontinued, replaced by .winmd metadata.  Excessively vague, the legacy portable device api is a million miles away from what you can expect to work on a IoT style device.  Have a look at the Windows.Devices namespace.

Comment: Thanks, at least now I know. The devices namespace doesn't really seem to be what I'm looking for, as it is intended for integrated devices, not devices plugged in over USB. I guess Linux is the better way to go then if you need solid driver support for USB devices...

Comment: @HansPassant Can you re-post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Somebody has to write a better question, one that doesn't require writing a book as an answer.  That somebody could be you.

Comment: please mark as answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Core libraries are included.  Many legacy libraries have been reworked into those core libraries.  I suggest checking the core libraries for the functionality you are looking for.  Libraries need to be compatible with the Windows Universal Platform.

You will need to write drivers for non-supported devices.